# How does electric current flow through a potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer

I'm very new to electronics so I'm still grasping some of the fundamentals. I'm trying to figure out exactly how a potentiometer works and how the current flows through a circuit with a potentiometer in it.

In the picture, if I move the wiper (B) down - further from A - will the resistance increase (and hence voltage drop increase) between A and B meaning a lower voltage will be supplied to the power amplifier.

I'm trying to visualize the path that the current is taking within this circuit. Does the current flow as I have drawn on the picture in blue?

[image: Potentiometer circuit sketch with annotations]

Comment: Thank very much everyone, blown away by the response! Potentiometers have just gone "click!" in my mind after reading and re-reading all of these comments. 

I can now continue working my way through Nigel P. Cook's "Electronics - A Complete Course" without the nagging thought that I had skimmed over a chapter without fully understanding it :) Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simplified circuit can be shown as follows,

Resistor **dR** is in series with the set of resistors **Rt-dR** and **Rin** of the amplifier.
 
The input impedance of the power amplifier can be neglected as it is comparatively larger,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnZeUR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the sliding contact is at A, **dR** is becomes equal to zero.

[image]

Hence **Rin=Rt-dR**

As the input impedance of the power amplifier is quite high the current at in the Ramp branch will be very low, hence the Ramp has no significance and can be neglected.

Also it can be seen that by moving the contact towards A the resistance dR is reduced which reduced the voltage drop, hence the voltage at the contact increases, at A the voltage is max and the volume is MAX.

As the contact is moved towards C the there will a large voltage drop across the dR as its value will be increased this will eventually lead to decrease in the contact voltage.

Think of **Rt-dR** resistance as a way to shunt the current to the ground, if its value is decreased then more current will shunt off to the ground and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> In the picture, if I move the wiper (B) down - further from A - will
>   the resistance increase (and hence voltage drop increase) between A
>   and B meaning a lower voltage will be supplied to the power amplifier.

Yes.

Perhaps it would help to consider the input impedance of the power amplifier to be very large (much greater than the potentiometer). As such, any small amount of current will develop a sizable voltage (labeled above as Vin).

To control this we could place a potentiometer (consider points A and B only and disconnect point C from ground) in series between the preamplifier and power amplifier.  However, since the resistance of this potentiometer (50Kohms) is likely much smaller than the input impedance of the power amplifier, the effect of turning the potentiometer is negligible.

So, instead, lets setup a path for the current from the pre amplifier with a lower resistance.  We can use the potentiometer (now consider points A and C) for this lower resistance path.

Now, if the wiper of the potentiometer was moved all the way to the "A" side of the potentiometer, Vin would be about (ignoring the impedance of the power amplifier's input) the current from the preamplifier times 50Kohm.  This is our maximum volume setting.  Let's call that Vmax.  If the wiper were moved half way between the "A" and "C" sides of the potentiometer, Vin would be cut in half.  That is:

Vin = Vmax * (25Kohms / 50Kohms) = Vmax * 1/2

And if we move the wiper all the way to the "C" side, Vin would be zero:

Vin = Vmax * (0ohms / 50Kohms) = Vmax * 0

This would be the minimum volume setting.  You shouldn't hear a thing out of the power amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

You've nearly got it. The part you are missing is that in a good design the input impedance (or resistance, if you like) will be much higher than that of the potentiometer. The result is that most of the current flows through the potentiometer and the amplifier just "listens-in" on the potentiometer. The effect is that the amplifier lightly-loads the potentiometer.

If the amplifier impedance is low relative to the potentiometer you might find that the output is lower than expected when the potentiometer is turned down.

Answer (score 0):

The full audio signal voltage amplitude appears across A-C.  If you insist on analyzing current flow, then essentially all of the current is flowing from A to C through the potentiometer. The audio signal current is actually heating up the potentiometer, but so slightly it is probably not measurable.

When B (the wiper) is all the way up at the top (A) end, the signal at B is essentially the full amplitude of the preamp output.  When the wiper (B) is down at the C end (ground), then the signal at B is essentially zero.

Your circuit demonstrates that potentiometers used as "volume controls" don't really operate in "current mode". Because the input impedance of the destination Power Amplifier is likely much (5-10X or more) higher than the impedance of the potentiometer, we don't analyze a circuit like this as "current flow", but rather as signal amplitude voltage.

Generally speaking, a potentiometer is used to "sample" the signal anywhere between the "C" end (ground = no signal). to the "A" end (full signal amplitude).